# Serialization.InvalidDataContractException was unhandled

Tags: c#, exception, serialization

```
public class SerializablionHelper
{
  public SerializablionHelper()
  {
    this.Entities = new Collection<Base>();
  }

  public ICollection<Base> Entities { get; set; }
}

// [DataContract]
// [KnownType(typeof(A))]
// [KnownType(typeof(B))]
public abstract class Base
{
}

[DataContract]
public class A : Base
{
  public int IntTest { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string StringTest { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class B : Base
{
  [DataMember]
  public int IntTest { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string StringTest { get; set; }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var objectA = new A { IntTest = 5, StringTest = "TestA" };
  var objectB = new B { IntTest = 25, StringTest = "TestB" };

  var serList = new SerializablionHelper();
  serList.Entities.Add(objectA);
  serList.Entities.Add(objectB);
  var dcSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SerializablionHelper));


  var xmlWriterSetting = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
  using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\test.xml", xmlWriterSetting))
  {
    dcSerializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, serList);
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get this exception.

Type 'XMLSerializer.Program+A' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.  Consider marking the base type 'XMLSerializer.Program+Base' with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or removing them from the derived type.

When I recommitted this code:

```
// [DataContract]
// [KnownType(typeof(A))]
// [KnownType(typeof(B))]
```

The code will working.

The problem I cannot make the base class as DataContract. 
Is there is any way to make this code working without Adding the DataContract to the base class or I have to take another serialization strategy?

Comment: Try to put the DataContract on SerializablionHelper will this help?

Comment: No same exception with other error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like that:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
public class SerializablionHelper
{
  public SerializablionHelper()
  {
    //this.Entities = new Collection<Base>();
  }
    // public ICollection<Base> Entities { get; set; }

  public Base A { get; set; }

  public Base B { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
}

[DataContract]
public class A : Base
{
  [DataMember]
  public int IntTest { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string StringTest { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class B : Base
{
  [DataMember]
  public int IntTest { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string StringTest { get; set; }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var objectA = new A { IntTest = 5, StringTest = "TestA" };
  var objectB = new B { IntTest = 25, StringTest = "TestB" };

  var serList = new SerializablionHelper { A = objectA, B = objectB };
  var dcSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SerializablionHelper));


  var xmlWriterSetting = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
  using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\test.xml", xmlWriterSetting))
  {
    dcSerializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, serList);
  }
}
```

I hope this will help.